# Moskito inspect monitoring tool integration with Java web application issue

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat7

I have an issue setting up an rmi port on Apache Tomcat server
`(set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401)`

Here are the steps i have done and getting the error respectively.

### Issue with MoSKito tool while configuring RMI port on Tomcat

I am also tried to configure MoSkito inspect on my java web application. as part of it, i have been trying to make RMI port using `"set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401"` on catalina.bat. there is no error as such but 9401 is not getting connected.

Steps followed:

```
1) My OS is Windows 7 
2) I have installed Apache Tomcat v7
3) I have downloaded Moskito inspect .war file from http://www.moskito.org/download.html and
4) Installed Moskito inspect on my tomcat server, the MoSKito inspect web UI is loading good.
5) I have created a sample java web application and deployed on same tomcat server. and web application also working good.
6) Now i have taken step to configure RMI port 9041 using below command on \bin\catalina.bat file(since i am on Windows OS).
```

I have put the below command on top of the file in `\bin\catalina.bat`
 `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401`

```
7) and started tomcat server, and then opened Moskito application on browser and gone to Quick Connect option on and given localhost and rmi port 9401 to call remote invocation.
Its failed.... its always giving error as MoSKito encountered an error:
```

**Cannot connect to localhost@localhost:9401, due: Can not resolve manually set reference. Server at localhost, port: 9401 is down or not properly configured**

[net.anotheria.moskito.webui.util.APILookupUtility.findRemote(APILookupUtility.java:168), net.anotheria.moskito.webui.util.APILookupUtility.findRemote(APILookupUtility.java:142), net.anotheria.moskito.webui.util.APILookupUtility.getAdditionalFunctionalityAPI(APILookupUtility.java:113),

> Q1: How to set -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401 on tomcat on Windows OS.
>   Q2: Once we set port, how to ensure port is set properly and its up and ready state for connection.
>   Q3: Once port is set properly, then how to set / configure specified java web application needs to be configured for MoSKito, since we could have more than one java web application on same tomcat server.

Please guide me, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to be able to connect to a MoSKito monitored application you have to enable an agent that binds itself to port 9401 and answers your replies. To do so, you have to add a dependency to your pom (if you are using maven):

```
  <!-- Enabling MoSKito Inspect Embedded -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
      <artifactId>moskito-inspect-remote</artifactId>
      <version>${moskito.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Please keep in mind that the current MoSKito version is 2.5.4 
If you are using a servlet 3.0 compatible container (tomcat 7, jboss wildfly) you are done. If you are using an older container you may need to add following to your web.xml:

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>net.anotheria.moskito.webui.embedded.StartMoSKitoInspectBackendForRemoteListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

If you are using no container at all, you can start it manually:

```
net.anotheria.moskito.webui.embedded.StartMoSKitoInspectBackendForRemote.startMoSKitoInspectBackend()
```

Now for you questions:

Q1: via catalina.bat. You were doing it correctly.

Q2: if the agent is configured everything will work correctly.

Q3: You may want to check out step by step guide here:

http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/the-complete-moskito-integration-guide-step-1/

Regards
Leon

Comment: Hi Leon thank you for spending your time here, 
here is more information
1. I am using Tomcat v7.0.21
2. I am not using Maven 
3. So i dont have an option to add dependency on pom.xml.
My environment:

Comment: This is My environment:
------------------------
1) I have build an java web application on eclipse without Maven and deployed on tomcat v7.
2) also i have deployed MoSkito webui inspect on same tomcat server. both apps are running good individually.
3) without Maven how can i bind/set port port on tomcat ?